# Grabbing text from an HTML tag using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to read something from within HTML tags and I'm completely stupid when it comes to Regular Expressions (I've though of a few patters and none seem to work).

I'm reading a web page, looking this line: `<td title='Visit Page for Demilict'><a href='personal.php?name=Demilict&amp;c=s' class='idk' rel='Demilict' style='color: teal;'>Demilict</a></td>`

I need to extract 'Demilict' from there, and there's 3 opportunities to do so as you can see.

Which would be the best position to extract it from and how would I achieve that?

I'm using this to find the name(s) as well, as there is around 60 different names I need to extract and they're all using the same format, except the name can only contain letters numbers and underscores.

```
public void parse(String list) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(list);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        Matcher matcher = namePattern.matcher(stringBuilder.toString());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("matched: " + matcher.group());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use DOM instead?

Comment: don't use RegEx to parse HTML - use a parser (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: We can't really help you without the actual pattern. Can you show us how you create `namePattern`? Also, consider using an API for HTML/XML processing (if it's XTHML, XML would do). Using regular expressions for such extraction is very error prone. Any unforeseen situation could create an issue.

Comment: How can I tell if it is XTHML?  I am using `namePattern` as `private Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("\\?obj=([A-Za-z0-9_]*)");`

Comment: just as a side note the \w regex special char is the same as A-Za-z0-9_

Comment: Alright well I wasn't aware that RegEx was a bad thing to use here, I'm still learning!  I've used DOM before for XML documents but I have no idea as to how I could use it for XHTML documents.

Comment: One word: JSoup. It's fast, easy and effective in extracting information from HTML whether it be XTHML or not.

Comment: @Ron: Regex is perfectly fine for simple problems like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a.*?>(\w+)</a>` will grab text between the `<a ...>` and the `< /a>` and put it into the first group; but as others have said regex probably isn't the best option here.

Edit: changes first + to * as 0 chars is valid. also removed the second ? as per comment below.

Comment: Nice and simple, but it could be simpler: you don't need the second question mark, because left angle bracket is not a word character.

Comment: ah very true thanks. also realised a * should replace the first + as 0 extra chars is valid as well (although that doesn't apply i this case).

Answer (score 1):

If you really would use Regular Expression to extract the name, this regexp should store the name in group 1:

```
<td[^>]*?><a[^>]*?>(\\w+)</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, to grab the text in the rel='XXX' attribute.

```
String val = "<td title='Visit Page for Demilict'><a href='personal.php?name=Demilict&amp;c=s' class='idk' rel='Demilict' style='color: teal;'>Demilict</a></td>";
String newVal = val.replaceFirst("^.*rel='([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'.*$", "$1");
System.out.println("Result: " + newVal);
```

Basically it just looks for rel='XXX', and throws everything except the XXX away. It allows for rel to contain chars a-z and A-Z, 0-9 and underscore.